# The White March, part I & II levels

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

My party is currently level 7 which according to all the sources I read, is about right to start the White March, part I.

Will I get enough experience in the White March to do it all without returning to the main map? Or is it more like the Endless Path, something you have to come and go as you level?

Is the answer different for part II?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of the Game Pressure guide on [Part I](http://guides.gamepressure.com/pillarsofeternity/guide.asp?ID=31663) and [Part II](http://guides.gamepressure.com/pillarsofeternity/guide.asp?ID=34454), it appears as if it is similar to the Endless Path: go there and do things till you get mushed into a thine paste then retreat to get more experience in easier locations.

The recommendations (for Part I) are as follow:

- Stalwart Village at level 7/8.
- Russetwood at level 10/11.
- Longwatch Falls level 11/12.
- Durgan's Battery at level 12 at a minimum.
- Crägholdt Bluffs at level14 at a minimum.

For Part II, the majority of encountered enemies will require a team at level 13-14 at least.

Clearly, **the difficulty selected will affect those levels requirements** included whether or not you used the scaling level option.

Comment: Meh, starting Cragholdt at around 11 is quite reasonable, just need to know when to quit. Even earlier it may be a good idea, for sneakily stealing a decent armor.